# Visual Studio 2005 quick file search

Tags: visual-studio-2005

In Eclispe you can do Ctrl+Shift+R and a Window popup where you can write the name of the file (or just the beginning of it) and to press enter to go directly to the file.

What is the equivalence in Visual Studio 2005? (Ctrl+Shift+F is not what I would like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a built-in command but there are some addons like [VS File Finder](http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/archive/2006/08/07/465056.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

From [Top 11 VS 2005 IDE tips and tricks:](http://www.chinhdo.com/20070920/top-11-visual-studio-2005-ide-tips-and-tricks-to-make-you-a-more-productive-developer/)

> This is the Find dropdown that is on the Standard Toolbar, not the Find dialog. Use the shortcut CTRL+D to activate the Find dropdown in normal mode. Use CTRL+/ to activate the Find dropdown in command mode
>
> To quickly go to a file, type CTRL+D, >open  <start of file name>. Intellisense works here just like in the Command Window. "of" (short for "open file") can be used instead of open.

Comment: Why it doesn'T work here? I have VS that told me (Ctrl+D) was pressed, Waiting for second key chord...

Comment: @Daok - is the find dropdown enabled on your toolbar? That's what gets focus in normal mode with this shortcut.

Comment: But I still can't use the short cut humm

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Find Combo - the one in the toolbar), write ">of " and the name of the file.
I am using ReSharper, so I am not sure if the shortcut is exactly this one in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an equivalence, but you can probably do it with the macro editor. It's pretty powerful and you can do pretty much what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

In plain VS.NET 2005, Go to the command window (Ctrl-D), type "openfile" (or just "of") and the file name.

If you have Resharper (and you should have it), you can type Ctrl-N and type in the class name, or Ctrl-Shift-N and type in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Gulzar proposed [VS File Finder](http://www.zero-one-zero.com/vs/) that was the greatest solution here.

But I installed [SonicFilFinder](http://jens-schaller.de/sonictools/sonicfilefinder/overview/index.htm) because the GUI was better. It works like a charm and you can use the HotKey you want. Really fast and no need of of the mouse. It's free.

Comment: hmm. i guess i have to give sonic a try. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010, you can use Edit > Navigate To... (Ctrl+comma).

Pro:

- Also searches objects/methods

Con:

- Doesn't support * wildcards
- Window isn't dockable

See: [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/12/19/walkthrough-quick-search-for-files-and-symbols-in-visual-studio-2010-lisa-feigenbaum.aspx)